# Calculating the volume of a solid of revolution about the y-axis question

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume

I am trying to find the correct answer for the volume of solid of revolution generated by revolving the region bounded by the following curves around the y-axis:
$$ y = \sqrt{25-x^{2}};   x = 3; y = 0$$

My solution:
when $x = 3$, $y =4$. I made the first equation as a function with respect to $y$ so that it is produced as $ x = \sqrt{25-y^{2}}$. I then used the equation:
$$\pi \int_{0}^{4}\left ( \sqrt{25-x^{2}} \right )^{2}dy$$
After working carefully and checking my arithmetic, I got an answer of $\frac{236\pi}{3}$. When I check the memo, it says the correct answer is  $\frac{128\pi}{3}$.

Can someone please help me find where I erred, I have a feeling I made a mistake before the integral step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since every point of the region satisfies $x\ge 3$, you need to have$$\pi\int_{0}^{4}\left(\left(\sqrt{25-y^2}\right)^2\color{red}{-3^2}\right)dy=\frac{128}{3}\pi.$$

Comment: Thank you, I got confused about the $x = 3$ because I was looking for functions with respect to $y$.

Comment: @user108104: You are welcome.